# Pass in a <li> when there is data with ternary operator in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, underscore.js

How can I optionally pass in a list item only if there's data in it? I'm storing all of my text information in `info.json`:

```
{
  "info": [
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "description": "Bob Vance of Vance Refrigeration"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kevin",
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "Jim",
      "description": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm mapping each of these items and rendering them onto the page only if there's content inside. As you can see, Kevin and Jim doesn't have any description, so I wouldn't render it onto the list.

```
info(item) {
  <div className="row">
    <ul>
      <li>{item.name}</li>
      <li>{item.description == "" ? undefined : item.description}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
} 

//this.props.office is passed down from `App.js` and contains the JSON that is shown above
render() {
  return (
    {(this.props.office).map((x) => this.info(x))}
  )
}
```

How can I avoid displaying the list item if `item.description` is an empty string? I tried to set it to undefined but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check for the existence of `description`, if it is available, call the `info()` method else return `false`. React won't render `Boolean` and `undefine`s.

Hope this helps!

```js
const config = {
  "info": [{
    "name": "Bob",
    "description": "Bob Vance of Vance Refrigeration"
  }, {
    "name": "Kevin",
    "description": ""
  }, {
    "name": "Jim",
    "description": ""
  }]
}

class App extends React.Component{
  info(item) {
   return <div className="row">
      <ul>
        <li>{item.name}</li>
        <li>{item.description}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  } 
  render(){
    const list = config.info.map((x) => x.description.length > 0 && this.info(x))
    return <div>
      {list}
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Saw this super late, but this worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to render items without description at all, you should [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it out from the array:

```
{(this.props.office)
   .filter((x) => x.description !== "")
   .map((x) => this.info(x))}
```

Furthermore I belive you have to return react element (jsx) from `info` method to make it work:

```
info(item) {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <ul>
        <li>{item.name}</li>
        <li>{item.description}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think this would filter the entire `item`, not just the description. I tested this and the name + description are both gone because it got filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Use a logical `or` because in react, a [Boolean "element" is ignored](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored) ([demo](http://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/ObyNoa?editors=1010)):

```
  <div className="row">
    <ul>
      <li>{item.name}</li>

      /* if the description is empty the result is true (and will be ignored), else  the result is the JSX */
      {item.description === '' || <li>{item.description}</li>} 

    </ul>
  </div>
```

However, if you're not sure if the description will be an empty string (""), and can be any "empty value" (undefined,  null) you can do this instead ([demo](http://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/bBVpZy?editors=1010)):

```
  <div className="row">
    <ul>
      <li>{item.name}</li>

      /* if the description is "", 0, null, or undefined it will be converted to false (and will be ignored), else  the result is the JSX */
      {!!item.description && <li>{item.description}</li>} 

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tested this and doesn't seem to work. The empty description element is still being rendered.

Comment: It works - I've added a demo. I'm not sure that the description is actually "", it can be null or undefined, so see the second solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can just wrap the condition around the `li`

```
info(item) {
  <div className="row">
    <ul>
      <li>{item.name}</li>
      {item.description !== "" && <li>item.description</li>}
    </ul>
  </div>
}
```